# In GLUT, how do I bind an action to a press of "any key"?

Tags: keyboard, glut, callbacks

Well, this sound ridiculous but the logic is escaping me. I have drawn my cube in OpenGL and I want to translate it to the right **if any of the key on the keyboard is pressed**. I know how to do this for specific keys but not for all the keys in one function? Do I have to code this for every key?

I was thinking to use [`glutSpecialFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node54.html) and [`glutKeyboardFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node49.html)? Is there any shorter way of doing this?

Comment: Reasoning for edit: OpenGL and GLUT are easy to confuse, but distinct. [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) is only a graphics API. [GLUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit) is a toolkit that creates an OpenGL context inside a windowing system, and that's what's handling windows, key presses, mouse events, and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `glutSpecialFunc` and `glutKeyboardfunction` is correct way. Whenever a key is pressed one of the function register this.

For example:

```
void pressKey(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
if(key=='w') close program (for example);
else movecube;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    initGL();
    glutCreateWindow("WINDOW");
    glutSpecialFunc(pressKey);
    glutKeyboardFunc(pressKey);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Whenever a key is pressed `pressKey` function is called and cube is moved. Anyway this wont work for some keys (ALT, CTRL, SHIFT or CAPSLOCK).

Comment: Yeah, I figured it to be the way out